# Where to use jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code I was given in jQuery and I am really new to it.  I need to use the jQuery.noConflict() method because I am using a Mootools framework as well.  I just don't know where I should replace the $ symbols in the code for 'jQuery'.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code for it is at www.cshellarchitecture.com/test/js/flexibg.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're structuring [your code](http://www.cshellarchitecture.com/test/js/flexibg.js) in a way something like the [module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/), you could do something like this:

```
var flexiBackground = (function($){ // notice the $ argument
  //$ === jQuery only within this scope...

})(jQuery.noConflict()); // call noConflict and pass the jQuery reference to $
```

By doing that, you will be able to reference to jQuery normally, by the `$` identifier *only inside* the scope of the self-executing anonymous function assigned to flexiBackground.

Comment: This should probably specify `true` to the `removeAll` parameter - otherwise it will still claim `jQuery`. Or, it could be rewritten as `jQuery.noConflict(); var f = (function ($) { .. })(jQuery);` to avoid hiding the side-effect.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly simple—after you type `jQuery.noConflict();` you should simply replace all `$` instances with `jQuery`.

Alternatively, if you're used to relying on `$` as a visual shorthand to discern when you are making calls to a framework, you can do `$jq = jQuery.noConflict();` and then on use `$jq` instead of `jQuery` throughout your code. In your cased you'd replace `$` with `$jq` in the code that's been provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples taken from your linked code file:

```
    var $window = $(window),
    $body = $('body'),
    imageID = "expando",
    tallClass = 'tall',
    wideClass = 'wide',
    $bgImage, $wrapper, img, url, imgAR;

    /**
            Are we dealing with ie6?
    */
    var ie6 = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 6);
```

Should be:

```
    var $window = jQuery(window),
    $body = jQuery('body'),
    imageID = "expando",
    tallClass = 'tall',
    wideClass = 'wide',
    $bgImage, $wrapper, img, url, imgAR;

    /**
            Are we dealing with ie6?
    */
    var ie6 = (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) <= 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery docs for the noConflict() method say:

> Run this function to give control of the $ variable back to whichever library first implemented it....By using this function, you will only be able to access jQuery using the 'jQuery' variable.

In which case, if you are running in no conflict mode, every call to jQuery via the "$" variable should be replaced with "jQuery".

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, it has helped tremendously!  I am just really new to jQuery, you all answered my question very well.  Thanks!